# Matplotlib side by side bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the following dataframe using matplotlib:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ["A", "A", "B", "B"], 'Z': ["a", "b", "a", "b"], 'Y': [5, 1, 10, 5]})
df

    X   Z   Y
0   A   a   5
1   A   b   1
2   B   a   10
3   B   b   5
```

What I want is two bar plots where the bars are next to each other rather than on top of each other. When I run this the bars are placed on top of each other:

```
plt.barh(df['X'][df['Z'] == "a"], df['Y'][df['Z'] == "a"], color = 'blue')
plt.barh(df['X'][df['Z'] == "b"], df['Y'][df['Z'] == "b"], color = 'red')
```

And whe I try changing the position of the bars I get the error: `can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want but you can try this:

```
df.set_index(['X','Z'])['Y'].unstack().plot.barh()
```

[image]

Or

```
df.set_index(['X','Z'])['Y'].unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Or

```
df.set_index(['X','Z'])['Y'].unstack().plot.barh(subplots=True, layout=(1,2))
```

[image]

or

```
df.set_index(['X','Z'])['Y'].unstack().plot.bar(subplots=True, layout=(1,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have the bars side by side you can use the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) library:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Y', hue='Z', y='X')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.barh`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html):

```
df.pivot(*df).plot.barh()
```

[image]

or

```
df.pivot(*df).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]